# php string replace after character #

Tags: php

We load a dynamic producttitle using the following code `<?php echo $producttitle; ?>`

Input could be:

**HP ProBook 450 G5 15.6 inch i5-8250U - 4LT51EA#ABB - Black**

This line is dynamic, so the code after the # can change and also be #ACC.

Should become:

**HP ProBook 450 G5 15.6" i5 - 4LT51EA - Black**

These product-titles can contain a value something like #.
It is always displayed as # without any spaces.
We want to remove the value # until the next space.

And these product-titles can also contain the value 15.6 inch, which we want to replace with 15.6". So the text inch should be replaced for the sign ".

We also want to change the value i5-8250U into i5. But i5 can also be i3 or i7. So it should replace everything from - until the next space.

How can we include both replacements inside this code?

I currently have the following:

```
<?php $trans = array(' inch' => '"'); ?>
<h1><?php echo strtr($producttitle, $trans); ?></h1>
```

But now I need to include the # part, how can we achieve that?

Comment: Hi, please show us an example of input and then what you want it to look like after all the fiddling

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, I added the example line.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks again, also added that.

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thanks, but that's not possible, because it is dynamic. #ABB can also be #ABC and - Black can also be - White. So it should find the # sign and replace it from there until the next space.

Comment: @ponury-kostek the point here is that they want a regex to find the product code #XYZ until the space and remove it along with the `inch`. Not just hard code it otherwise they'd be hard coding thousands of product IDs.

Comment: [`sscanf()`](https://php.net/sscanf) can do the job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you might so is use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and create an array with 2 regexes and an array with 2 replacements.

In the replacement you could refer to the first capturing group with `$1` to keep that as the replacement.

**First part**

```
\s+inch\s+(i[357])-\w+
```

- `\s+inch\s+` Match 1+ whitespace characters, `inch` and then 1+ whitespace characters (To not also match newlines, you could use `\h+` instead of `\s` to match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters)
- `(i[357])` Capturing group to match i followed by 3, 5, or 7
- `-` Match literally
- `\w+` Match 1+ times a word character

Replace with

```
" $1
```

**Second part**

```
(\w+)#\w+
```

- `(\w+)` Capturing group which matches 1+ word characters
- `#\w+` Match `#` followed by 1+ word characters

Replace with

```
$1
```

For example:

```
$string = 'HP ProBook 450 G5 15.6 inch i5-8250U - 4LT51EA#ABB - Black';
$find = array('/\s+inch\s+(i[357])-\w+/', '/(\w+)#\w+/');
$replace = array('" $1', '$1');
$result = preg_replace($find, $replace, $string);
echo $result; // HP ProBook 450 G5 15.6" i5 - 4LT51EA - Black
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/34bSM)

Comment: @Script47 I think you are referring to lazy quantifiers. Perhaps [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) and [this page](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) can be helpful.

Comment: Many thanks, that works perfect. But I forgot some part of the code, see my edit. There is also a i3, i5 or i7 part, which we need to replace. How can we edit your code, that this will also works perfect?

Comment: @HenkZ If the i3, i5 or i7 part is always there, perhaps like this https://3v4l.org/1jQ9g

Comment: Thanks! For some strange reason, does this new code not work in my live webpage. I get the following value: HP ProBook 450 G5 15.6 inch i5-8250U - 4LT51EA - Black. It works fine with your code, but when replacing $string = $producttitle; it does echo that value.

Comment: @HenkZ The example string is that the exact string from the page? I have updated the code a bit to let the first regex match 1+ times a whitespace character instead of a space. https://3v4l.org/O1pZn

Comment: @HenkZ You are welcome. The `\s+` also matches newlines. If you don't want to match those, you could also try `\h+` to match 1+ horizontal whitespace characters.

Comment: Seems that the inch does not work well with the following code: ASUS C202SA-GJ0061 11.6 inch N3060 - C202SA-GJ0061. Any idea why?

Comment: That is because that variation does not contain i3 i5 or i7.

Comment: Indeed, but sometimes the variation does not contain i3, i5 or i7. Only in some cases, do you know how to rewrite the code to make it work in both cases?

Comment: @HenkZ Do you mean like this with an optional group? https://3v4l.org/KQKNd

Comment: Thanks again! But I did not mean to get it into a group. But sometimes the product name contains the value i3,i5 or i7 but sometimes it does not. Because it loads the string dynamically, it can change sometimes. So I need the code, that it checks if there is any i3-, i5-, i7- value an replace that. If not it should skip that part, but it should in that case still replace the value inch for " if that is in the line. So the i3,i5,7 part is not always in the string. How can we modify the code for that?

Comment: @HenkZ The group is used in the replacement and if it is not there, nothing is replaced. Did the last demo not work correct?

Comment: For some reason it does not work with this line: ASUS C101PA-FS002 10.1 inch - 90NB0EP1-M00090. See https://3v4l.org/9jePK.

Comment: Thanks again, but it does not work well with the first line: ASUS C101PA-FS002 10.1 inch - 90NB0EP1-M00090. That also removes the first part of 90NB0EP1-M00090. Sorry, but it is quite a complex one.

Comment: I now have only one problem left. This line "HP EliteDisplay E233 23 inch Full HD - 1FH46AT#ABB" returns into: "HP EliteDisplay E233 23" HD - 1FH46AT" But it should return: HP EliteDisplay E233 23" Full HD - 1FH46AT

Comment: @HenkZ I think it returns what you expect right? https://3v4l.org/Esv6b